# How can I specify the scheme specific part in a data tag for an intent-filter?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I want to set up a BroadcastReceiver to handle PACKAGE_REPLACED, but I only want to be notified when my package is replaced.  It works fine if I specify a data tag with scheme="package" but then I get notified when any application is reinstalled or upgraded.  I can't figure out how I'm supposed to specify the package name which is in the scheme specific part -- that is, when my BroadcastReceiver gets the intent in onRecieve(), if I do intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart(), that's the package name, but is there any way I can filter for only that in my intent-filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest would be to accept any broadcast intents with the `package` scheme as you say, but do the filtering based on the `Intent` extras that are sent with the `PACKAGE_*` actions.

If the package name in the `Intent` doesn't match yours, just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

As used in Google Search App:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" /> 
  <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

But according to my rough test, this can still catch any updated package, which renders the "android:path" part actually useless.

For Android 3.1+, you can use this new action to respond only when your package updated:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

If you have to support back to Android 2.x, a better practice is to declare 2 separate receivers for `PACKAGE_REPLACED` and `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`. Then upon first run, check the runtime Android version and disable the old one if version is 3.1+.